# XML Syntax for Schtasks.exe

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am writing a program in VB.NET which creates highest-privilege scheduled tasks using an XML document and the schtasks.exe command line tool. The problem that I have run into is which XML tag to use for the highest privilege option and where to place it in the document. The current document is below, sorry about the indentation (it does not import correctly):

```
<Task xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
<RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2005-10-11T13:21:17-08:00</Date>
    <Author>AuthorName</Author>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <Description>Admin Task</Description>
</RegistrationInfo>
<Triggers>
    <!--
<CalendarTrigger>
        <StartBoundary>2005-10-11T13:21:17-08:00</StartBoundary>
        <EndBoundary>2006-01-01T00:00:00-08:00</EndBoundary>
        <Repetition>
            <Interval>PT1M</Interval>
            <Duration>PT4M</Duration>
        </Repetition>
        <ScheduleByDay>
            <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
        </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
    -->
</Triggers>
<Principals>
<Principal id="Author">
    <RunLevel>Highest</RunLevel><!--Not correct...-->
</Principal>
</Principals>

<Settings>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
     <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
<DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    </Settings>
    <Actions>
        <Exec>
            <Command>notepad.exe</Command>
        </Exec>
    </Actions>
</Task>
```

PS: I am rather inexperienced with writing XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the correct XML tag location and syntax by exporting the settings I needed out of Scheduled Tasks.  For others with a similar problem, a working template is posted below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2014-04-13T16:02:17.9854869</Date>
    <Author>[username]</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers />
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>[username]</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
      <IdleSettings>
        <StopOnIdleEnd>false</StopOnIdleEnd>
       <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
     </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>[command]</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```